# Using the Rails form builder and Draper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formbuilder, draper

I'm giving Draper a try as an alternative to helpers. I get the cases where I am just formatting the information. But what about interacting with the Rails form builder. For example if I wanted to output a string or a select box depending on some context. Do I pass the form builder as an argument. So in my decorator:

```
def role_or_select form
  available_roles = h.policy_scope User::ROLES
  if available_roles.include? role
    form.input :role, collection: available_roles, include_blank: false
  else
    role
  end
end
```

Then in my view:

```
= simple_form_for user do |form|
  ...
  = user.role_or_select_on form
  ...
```

Is there a more elegant method?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a somewhat elegant solution to this. I created the following module and mixed it into my decorators:

```
module FormDecoration

  def form options={}, &blk
    h.simple_form_for model, options do |builder|
      @form_builder = builder
      blk[builder]
    end
  ensure
    @form_builder = nil
  end

  def method_missing meth, *args, &blk
    if @form_builder && @form_builder.respond_to?(meth)
      @form_builder.public_send meth, *args, &blk
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def respond_to? meth
    (@form_builder && @form_builder.respond_to?(meth)) || super
  end
end
```

Now my view can be this:

```
= user.form do
  = user.input :name
  = user.input :email
  = user.role_or_select
```

The `input` method is proxied off to the form builder. The role_or_select is defined in my helper to look something like this:

```
  def role_or_select
    available_roles = h.policy_scope User::ROLES
    if available_roles.include? object.role
      input :role, collection: available_roles, include_blank: false
    else
      object.role
    end
  end
```

This even allows me to do things like add the form options in the decorator. For example adding the following to my UserDecorator will turn off the auto-complete:

```
def form options={}
  options[:html] ||= {}
  options[:html][:autocomplete] = 'off'
  super options
end
```